# Когда — не знаем

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Как правильно, филины?

1. Хотим приехать все время. Когда, не знаем.
2. Хотим приехать все время. Когда — не знаем.

Я думаю, второй вариант верен.

Answer (score 4):

Оба варианта возможны:

(1) *Хотим приехать все время. Когда, **не знАем.***
(2) *Хотим приехать все время. **КогдА** — не знАем.*

Варианты различаются **по интонации**. В первом случае нет ясно обозначенного ударения, оно уходит на конец фразы. Пауза также небольшая. Во втором предложении ударение и пауза подчеркнуты. Другими словами, ставьте тире, если хотите подчеркнуть "когда", и **запятую,** если подчеркиваете "не знаем". Тире — это более ожидаемый вариант.

Розенталь **разрешает** ставить тире, но это **неосновной** знак. Тире вместо запятой может использоваться в СПП с разной **структурой** главного и придаточного предложений.

**По Розенталю** ([Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142)):
Тире ставится для интонационного отделения главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего **тире** употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует: 1) придаточная **изъяснительная:** *Появились какие-то новые слухи о нём, но **какие** — неизвестно*; *Он придёт, но **когда** — не знаю* (ср. при другом порядке частей: *Не знаю, когда он придёт*).

**Грамматическая справка** (в качестве бонуса от филинов)

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, придаточное предложение состоит из одного союзного слова ***когда***. Главное предложение (***не знаем***) односоставное определенно-личное.

Comment: Sharon, вам не кажется, что построено всё слишком по-разговорному? То есть, конечно, понятно, о чём речь. Но если было бы так: *"Приедем. Когда – не знаем"*, то вопроса бы у меня не возникло. А так получается, что "когда" ссылается на "хотим приехать": *"Когда хотим – не знаем"*.

Comment: Да, вы правы, какой-то странный диалект при выборе грамматики. Возможный диалог: "Вы же хотели к нам приехать" - Да все только (да все время) собираемся, а когда – не знаем.

Comment: @Pumpkin777  Пожалуйста, не забывайте отмечать все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой вверх. А также, мне кажется, вам стоит принять этот ответ.